# Open a web browser popup in command line

Tags: windows, browser, cmd, popup

Is there a way to open a web browser popup in command line on Windows 7 ?

I need to pass it some arguments :

- Popup width and height
- Popup url to open when launched
- Position X and Y
- Display no address bar

Comment: The command I need to execute is a simple _window.open_. I tried to use the following command line with **wscript.exe** but as it is not related to a browser, it doesn't know the window object 


`window.open('http://myurl.com/', 'width=560, height=768, top=100, left=100, directories=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no, resizable=no')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution myself. It was in fact really simple, here it is :

## Solution

Create a new **html** file (in this exemple it will be created under *c:\openPopup.html*), containing a simple **script** tag :

```
<script>
    window.resizeTo(with,height);
    window.moveTo(x,y); // (0,0) is the top-left corner of the screen
    window.location('http://url-you-want-to-open-as-popup/');
</script>
```

Open a new **cmd**, then type

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" c:\openPopup.html
```

## Explanations

We're using a proxy to open a popup. We're launching our proxy (*openPopup.html*) which contains the instructions to transform the window in popup. Then it navigates to the URL specified in the window.location instruction.

I haven't found a way to hide the address bar yet but it wasn't mandatory. A nice feature would be to pass the url as an argument.

Hope it helps someone !